# node js express session how to keep same for all path and page reload till the browser is open

Tags: node.js, express, express-session

test.js - express code

```
var express = require('express');
var session = require('express-session');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser());
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
   res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
   res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");  
   next();
 });
 
 app.use(session({  
   secret: 'somerandonstuffs',
   resave: false,
   saveUninitialized: false  
 }));
  
 app.listen(4000, () => {    
   console.log("server running on port....", 4000);
   });
   
   app.get('/getsession', function(request , response){
     console.log("getsession::", request.sessionID);  
     if(request.session.uname){     
         response.json({username: request.session.uname});
      } else {       
         response.json({username: "no user"});
      }     
   });
   
   app.post('/savesession',  function(request , response){            
      request.session.uname = request.body.loginuname;
      console.log("save session::", request.session);
      response.json({username: request.session.uname});
   });
```

app.js - user/client code

```
function login(){       
           $.ajax({
                url: 'http://127.0.0.1:4000/getsession',
                type: 'get',
                dataType: 'json',
                crossDomain: true,                              
                success: function(result){
                    console.log( "result::: ", result );
                },
                error: function(xhr, resp, text){                   
                    console.log("xhr:: ", xhr , "resp::: ", resp , "text::: ", text);
                }
            });
                
        $("#ahrefbtn").on('click', function(){  
           var data = $("#formdata").serializeArray();          
           $.ajax({
                    url: 'http://127.0.0.1:4000/savesession',
                    type: 'post',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: data,
                    success: function(result){
                     console.log( "result::: ", result );
                   },
                error: function(xhr, resp, text){                   
                    console.log("xhr:: ", xhr , "resp::: ", resp , 
                    "text::: ", text);
                }
            });
   
    $(document).ready(function(){   
      login();  
    });
```

Above code works fine for postman get and post requests.
But when I use browser-chrome(session cookies allowed) on page reload/refresh it creates new sessionid and each time new session is getting generated.
How do i get same session each time to retrieve last session data.
In app.js on page reload/refresh it calls getsession api and on button click it it calls savesession api.
app.js api calls are executes properly.

Comment: Anybody here to provide solution

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34324460/express-session-not-saving-nodejs